# Ошибка в отправке Http Put запроса с помощью ajax в ASP.NET MVC приложении

Tags: ajax, asp.net, mvc

в папке Models есть такая простая модель:

```
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

В контроллере UserController, который обрабатывает запрос, написан следующий код:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // PUT: /User/Edit
    [HttpPut]
    public JsonResult Edit(int id, User user)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Put request is working"); //не выполняется
        return Json("Response from Edit");
    }
}
```

И сама отправка запроса из файла Index.cshtml

```
/*PUT*/
$.ajax({
    url: '/User/Edit',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: 100, user: { name: 'Dmitry', email: 'dmitry@gmail.com' } }),
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);  //это не работает
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error'); //срабатывает эта строка
    }
});
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос сведения об ошибке

Comment: error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                      alert(xhr.status);
                      alert(thrownError);
                  }
Выдает:
404
Not Found

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему добавлением такого блока в файл Web.config после тега 
`<system.webServer>`

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```